What ways exist to make MSVCR100.dll run under windows 95?
I am currently backporting a lot of applications to windows 95. Now I want to backport some webbrowsers but most of them rely on msvcrt100.dll. I had some sucess in making them use msvcr80.dll instead but not much. Now I want to know if there is a way to make the real msvcr100.dll running so I can get more applications to run
As already said I tried redirecting calls to msvcr80.dll I also tried backporting msvcr100.dll, and I tried using other versions of  the dll from projects like reactos.
I want a way to somehow get the file to run, maybe someone who is more into backporting then me (I literally just started 2 weeks ago) knows of a way. Or a way to simulate a msvcr100.dll being present.
I also tried to search for an existing backport but to no avail

Windows 95 is almost 30 years old. Just don't.

you  could always try a wrapper

@Luke — If the goal is to support old slow hardware that can only carry Windows 95, it will be much easier to setup some modern Linux software that would run faster than Windows 95 30 years ago. :-)

@nbk I will try that. although I never done it before.

@Luke What else should I do in my freetime ;)
